# Why am I getting a AmazonS3Exception?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

my task is to encrypt a file that is uploaded to S3. The upload worked fine before the encryption but now after I encrypted the file I get this exception.
`The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema`

I added this to the existing Code

```
        final AwsCrypto crypto = new AwsCrypto();

        try (
            final FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(encryptfile);
            final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            final CryptoOutputStream<?> encryptingStream = crypto.createEncryptingStream(crypt, out)) 
        {
            IOUtils.copy(in, encryptingStream);
        }
```

My thoughts, Why does AmazonS3 expect a XML-File ? Why not a normal text document ?
Is there a Option to change this maybe with the Bucket Policy ?

**EDIT** 
That is the upload code, maybe there is a Issue. I dont understand why it´s working without the encryption.

```
             File uploaffile = encryptFile(file);
             List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
             String filename = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

             InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(awss3bucket, filename);
             InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = amazons3.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
             long partSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
             long contentLength = uploaffile.length();
             long filePosition = 0;
             for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++) {
                 partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));

                 UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                         .withBucketName(awss3bucket)
                         .withKey(filename)
                         .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
                         .withPartNumber(i)
                         .withFileOffset(filePosition)
                         .withFile(uploaffile)
                         .withPartSize(partSize);

                 PartETag petag = new PartETag(amazons3.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getPartNumber(), amazons3.uploadPart(uploadRequest).getETag());
                 partETags.add(petag);

                 filePosition += partSize;
             }

             CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(awss3bucket, filename,
                                                                                            initResponse.getUploadId(), partETags);

             amazons3.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
```

Comment: It doesn't care about the contents of your file. Part of what is ultimately going to be an HTTP request is formatted as XML, and for some reason that's wrong.

Comment: Since AWS is complaining about an HTTP request that neither you nor we can see, I don't think the code is going to be overly helpful. Either dig down into the code with a debugger until you see the XML, or listen to the HTTP traffic (e.g. fiddler, wireshark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe next time I should stop to copy some random Code from the Internet. 
You use The FileoutputStream to write not the other way. So the File so was Empty which created the Exception.

```
        CryptoInputStream<KmsMasterKey> encryptingStream = crypto.createEncryptingStream(crypt, in);
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(encryptfile);
            IOUtils.copy(encryptingStream, out);
            encryptingStream.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
```